Aligning columns with multicolumn header
I'm trying to set up a table with multicolumn headers of variable width, some of them pretty long.
My code looks more or less like this:
\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Very, very, very, very, really long heading 1} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Not that long heading 2} \\
\hline
Sub-heading 1 & Sub-heading 2 & Sub-heading 3 & Sub-heading 4 \\
\hline
Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 & Data 4 \\
Data 5 & Data 6 & Data 7 & Data 8 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

and the end product looks like this:

What I don't like about it is that the second column, under Sub-heading 2, takes up too much space. I'd like for columns 1 and 2 to have equally distributed space (and same for columns 3 and 4). I looked at the replies for this question but they seem to be a bit too hacky (and I couldn't get the spacing right for my document anyway). Any ideas?

Off-topic: \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Not that long heading 2} should be changed to \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Not that long heading 2} in order to avoid getting a double-width vertical separator line between the two long headings.

Nice catch here as well @Mico -- thanks!

Here are three solutions. Hopefully, you'll judge that they aren't too hacky...
The first solution employs the w column type that's provided by the array package to make the first two data columns have equal width and be centered below the very long heading.
IMNSHO, this solution will be problematic whenever the resulting width of columns 1 and 2 is much larger than the natural width of columns 3 and 4. If the natural widths of the four data columns are  roughly equal (as is the case here), it may be preferable to employ these natural widths -- and to force the very long header to line-wrap. This idea is pursued in Solution 2.
Solution 3 is very similar to Solution 2, except that it purposefully generates a much more open "look" by (a) getting rid of all vertical lines and (b) using the macros of the booktabs package -- specifically: \toprule, \cmidrule, \midrule, and \bottomrule -- instead of \hline.
Solution 1 works by computing the widths of columns 1 and 2 as a function of the width of the very, very, very long header that spans these two columns. In contrast, solutions 2 and 3 work by computing the usable width of the common header that spans columns 1 and 2 as a function of the widths of columns 1 and 2, and to employ a centered version of the p column type for the very, very, very long header.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\fi
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type % for Solution 1
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering}p{\dimeval{#1}}} % for Solutions 2 and 3
\usepackage{booktabs} % for Solution 3
\newlength\mylen % scratch length variable

\usepackage[skip=0.2\baselineskip]{caption} % just for this example
\addtolength\textwidth{0.25in} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering

\newcommand\longheading{Very, very, very, very, really long heading 1}

% Solution 1
\settowidth{\mylen}{\longheading} % measure width
\caption*{Solution 1}
\begin{tabular}{| *{2}{w{c}{\dimeval{\mylen/2-\tabcolsep}}} | cc |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\longheading} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Not that long heading 2} \\
\hline
Sub-heading 1 & Sub-heading 2 & Sub-heading 3 & Sub-heading 4 \\
\hline
Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 & Data 4 \\
Data 5 & Data 6 & Data 7 & Data 8 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip


% Solution 2
\settowidth{\mylen}{Sub-heading 1Sub-heading 2} % measure width
\caption*{Solution 2}
\begin{tabular}{| cc | cc |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|P{\dimeval{\mylen+2\tabcolsep}}|}{\longheading} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Not that long heading 2} \\
\hline
Sub-heading 1 & Sub-heading 2 & Sub-heading 3 & Sub-heading 4 \\
\hline
Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 & Data 4 \\
Data 5 & Data 6 & Data 7 & Data 8 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip


% Solution 3
%\settowidth{\mylen}{Sub-heading 1Subheading 2} % measure width
\caption*{Solution 3}
\begin{tabular}{@{} cc cc @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}P{\mylen+2\tabcolsep}}{\longheading} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Not that long heading 2} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
Sub-heading 1 & Sub-heading 2 & Sub-heading 3 & Sub-heading 4 \\
\midrule
Data 1 & Data 2 & Data 3 & Data 4 \\
Data 5 & Data 6 & Data 7 & Data 8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}


Oe \settowidth{\mylen}{Sub-heading 1\hspace{2\tabcolsep}Sub-heading 2}

@JohnKormylo - good one!

Solution 1 worked like a charm -- thanks a lot! Just to clarify, what I found hacky about the answer in the other question was manually setting the number of ems :)

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix, you can split a cell a two cells of the same size (with the command \Block).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|cc|}[&-in-blocks]
\Hline
Very, very, very, very, really long heading 1 
& \Block{1-2}{Not that long heading 2} \\
\Hline
\Block{}{Sub-heading 1 & Sub-heading 2} & Sub-heading 3 & Sub-heading 4 \\
\Hline
\Block{}{Data 1 & Data 2} & Data 3 & Data 4 \\
\Block{}{Data 5 & Data 6} & Data 7 & Data 8 \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}

You need several compilations (because nicematrix uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).


However, I recommend a design in the spirit of booktabs (see Mico's answer).

I don't think that the OP wants vertical rules between columns 1 & 2 and columns 3 & 4.

You are right: I have changed my answer.

Thanks a lot for your reply as well -- wish I could accept more than one answer!
